# how to build envoy binary without CI?

Tags: envoyproxy

I only want to build envoy. It seems like `x./ci/run_envoy_docker.sh './ci/do_ci.sh bazel.dev'` will also run CI. How can I only compiled and build the binary?

Answer (score 0):

`bazel build //source/exe:envoy-static`

Look at here: https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/master/bazel/README.md#quick-start-bazel-build-for-developers